# How to add redirect URIs programmatically?

Tags: google-api, command-line-interface, google-oauth

I manage an app which is available on a lot (>50) of different domains, and which uses Google OAuth 2.0 for authentication. I've seen [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23717452/how-to-add-multiple-redirect-uris-for-google-oauth-2) that it's possible to add several redirect URIs by separating them with a newline; but is there a way to do this programmatically, for instance with a CLI tool?

The closest thing I could find is [gcloud auth](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/), but it says nothing about adding redirect URIs.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have Google redirect to a single central location (`auth.yourapp.com`) then redirect to a specific domain (`yourapp.customer.com`) from there? Then you won't have to inform Google every time you add or remove a domain.

Comment: @Wander Nauta Unfortunately I'm not at liberty of changing this

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ? Thanks

Comment: @cyberjoac I didn't find a proper solution, no; as a workaround, a colleague of mine wrote a selenium script that automatically inserted the URLs in the web form

Comment: @LoicAG are you able to share the selenium script you've used as a workaround?

Comment: @Andrew unfortunately not, sorry, it was many jobs ago...